# C# Abstract methods with abstract parameters

Tags: c#, abstract, extends

Hi i'm trying to implement a structure where by I need to be able to create an abstract method in an abstract class in C#, which has an abstract object as a parameter.. example-

```
public abstract class AbstractMapper
{
     protected abstract AbstractObject doLoad(AbstractObject obj);
}

public abstract class UserMapper
{
     protected override User doLoad(User obj)
     {

     } 
}
```

In this example the "User" class extends the "AbstractObject" class... This is giving me errors on compile. Can someone advise on how i should achieve the above?

Comment: What are these errors? Anyway, you are trying to override a method that doesn't exist, so you can't override it

Comment: It looks to me like you need to use generics. The base class would be AbstractMapper<T> and UserMapper would implement AbstractMapper<User>

Comment: Ah, I've got the message. You need to make `AbstractMapper` generic in order to use abstract object type in overriden methods.

Comment: Also, IIRC, `abstract` is a type of *Class*, not a type of *object*.

Answer (score 5):

Use a generic type parameter on `AbstractMapper` constrained to be a subtype of `AbstractObject`:

```
public abstract class AbstractMapper<T> where T : AbstractObject
{
     protected abstract T doLoad(T obj);
}

public class UserMapper : AbstractMapper<User>
{
     protected override User doLoad(User obj)
     {
         ...
     } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is causing me problems because im unable to create an instance of the UserMapper because its abstract...removing that makes it work great :) thanks

Comment: @user3071089 You're the one who made it `abstract` in your question. :) Simply remove the `abstract` keyword if you don't want it.

Comment: haha i didnt realise i had.. have removed it and working well. thanks! time to read into generics

Answer (score 1):

UserMapper is extending Object class and you are trying to override a method that doens't exist (doLoad).

Also, the signature of the method has a return type of User and you are not returning anything.

If you want User class to extend AbstractObject class, then do this:

```
public class User : AbstractObject 
{
      protected AbstractObject doLoad(AbstractObject obj)
      {
            // do something here and return an instance of a class that extends Abstract object
            return null; // added to make it compile
      }
}
```

Do you know that the access modifier protected means that it is only visible inside the class and in child classes? Read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx